# UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() returns nil -what now?

Tags: ios, swift3, cocoapods

I'm writing an iOS application and integrated [FDWaveformView](https://github.com/fulldecent/FDWaveformView) 2.0.0 via CocoaPods.
Sometimes UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() returns nil and I get the "FDWaveformView failed to get graphics context" log message.

```
   guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
        NSLog("FDWaveformView failed to get graphics context")
        return
    }
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Why guard ? http://radex.io/swift/guard/

Comment: @Murloc - This is perfect example of appropriate use of `guard`. Joern is obviously about to do a bunch of other stuff with that `context` and wants an early exit if he didn't get one. Nothing wrong with `guard` here.

Comment: Joern, the problem isn't the call to `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext`, but rather where you called it from. You're obviously not calling it from a valid context (e.g. from within `draw` or in between a `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` and `UIGraphicsEndImageContext`.) I'd suggest adding a breakpoint where this message is logged and then looking at the stack and figuring out how you called this outside of a valid context. But there's not enough here for us to diagnose it for you.

Comment: Thank you all so far! I will debug into the library code and see what's happening there

Comment: within draw() of what object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by updating to 2.1.0

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that You are calling UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() inside draw(_ rect : CGRect)() method.

Also ensure that you are not manually calling draw(_ rect : CGRect). Instead call setNeedsDisplay() which will call draw(_ rect : CGRect).